# Add number of days to Date object in jQuery always shows wrong days in a month

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to traverse through Date object adding single day with a for loop.  However when I loop and add single day do Date object per each iteration I end up with 30 days in a month no matter which month I try (even february).  I must say jQuery isn´t my strongest syntax so I´m looking to you guys.  Due to practical matters in my project I need to show only 30 days in my view no matter which date I select.

How can I add a single day per each iteration but still preserving days in each month?

```
var date = new Date(2014, 10, 10);

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    // do stuff with my date object ... abbreviated

    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);  
    //I thought this was enough, but october is showing only 30 days
    //Should I use another method when adding days?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's November. Months are 0-bases.

```
var date = new Date(2014, 10, 10);
console.log(date)
> Mon Nov 10 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate):

```
var theBigDay = new Date(1962, 6, 7); // 1962-07-07
```

Comment: True, but he says that it comes back with 30 days no matter what month. Even February.

Comment: Well... actually I should have looked closer, february came out with 31 days which supports what @meager said about months being zero-based.  Thank you for this answer, that did the trick ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to reconsidered that there are months that have 30 days. If you based on the calendar, these are the months that have 30 days, September, April, June and November. The rest of the months have 31 days except February. Also, try to considered leap year of which February will end at 29 and if not it will end at 28.

I hope this help you.